# Is it generally true that area changes quadratically as length changes linearly?

Tags: geometry, area

I was recently told that area changes quadratically as length changes linearly, in the context of a cone.

Is it generally true that area changes quadratically as length changes linearly? If not, what class of shapes does this apply to and which ones does it not?

Comment: Yes, it is true: if you have a shape of perimeter $P$ and of area $A$, if you multiply all lengths by $\alpha$, the new perimeter will become $\alpha P$ and the new area $\alpha^2 A$. That's why 1km=10^3m but 1km^2=10^6m^2 (here, $\alpha$ is 1000).

Comment: and the volume changes as the cube. That's can be pretty easily spotted with what physicists call _dimensional analysis_. Side note: for some special objects, the area varies as $\alpha^d$, where $d$ is not an integer; see [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension).

Comment: This scaling property is, with some tweaks to make it rigourous, the very _definition_ of two-dimensional in many books. [This video](https://youtu.be/gB9n2gHsHN4) is mainly about the objects that usually fall between, namely fractals, but he talks about line segments, squares and cubes as well.

Comment: @anderstood thanks for the response. That's amazing -- I can't believe that I never connected the two. What about an equilateral triangle, though? I'm using google's calculator for the area of an equilateral triangle, and it doesn't seem to change quadratically as I increase the length of the sides? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Provided the shape remains proportional.  And volume of solids cubically.  And in n dimensions to the n-th power.  It's obvious for squares and circles and using the idea of limits (which is how we know the area of a circle in the first place) it holds for all.

Comment: @ThePointer The area of an triangle is $Bh/2$. If you multiply all lengths by $\alpha$, of course it's perimeter will be multiplied by $\alpha$, and the area will become $(\alpha B)(\alpha h)/2=\alpha^2 Bh/2$: you see that the area is multiplied by $\alpha^2$. PS: this might be of interest: [list of fractals by their dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension).

Comment: @anderstood Google's calculator has the area of an equilateral triangle as $A = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a$. If $a = 2$, then $A = 1.73$; If $a = 3$, then $A = 3.9$?

Comment: @ThePointer An area is certainly not what you have written. There's a square missing ($a^2$). An area in square meters (for example), not meters as with your formula!

Comment: @anderstood Sorry, that was a mistake on my part; indeed, it is $a^2$. But doesn't "change quadratically" mean it is squared each time? It doesn't seem like the area of an equilateral triangle is being squared each time I increase the length of the sides? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: If you multiply the length of each side by $\alpha$, the area is multiplied by $\alpha^2$. As simple as that. I think you are confusing _squaring the lengths_ and _squaring the factor_.

Comment: For polygons, cut the polygon into triangles.  This is true for each triangle ($\frac 12 (b*c)(h*c)=\frac 12 bh*c^$).  For other shapes.  Well, set up a two or more functions to describe the perimeter and a set of integers to describe the area. $\int_{ca}^{cb} cf (x/c)dx$. If $u=x/c$ then substitution yields $\int_a^b c^2f (u)du$.

Comment: @anderstood Ok, I understand now. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another perspective on your question, starting from your comment that you're interested "in the context of a cone".

In the plane when you scale all lengths by a factor $\lambda$ you scale all areas by $\lambda^2$.

That's true too for shapes on a cone, because a cone is *developable*: you can cut it along a ray from the point and unroll it to lie flat without distorting any dimensions.

The cylinder is developable too, so areas go by the square of lengths there.

The sphere is different. When you scale a triangle from small to large the area increases faster than quadratically. You can see that because a small (equilateral) triangle is nearly flat while the equilateral triangle with three right angles (sides the equator and two perpendicular meridians) bulges, so its area is "larger than it would be in the plane". In fact, on the sphere similar triangles must be congruent, so the whole idea of "scaling" is tricky.

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP: you're talking about [that kind of triangles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html).

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you very much for this insight.

Comment: Ethan, so although this property holds for all 2D shapes, it does not hold for all 3D shapes?

Comment: @ThePointer My discussion is about 2D shapes on a  curved 2D surface (that happens to be embedded in 3D space). The comments discuss how the scaling works in higher dimensions in ordinary flat Euclidean space.